# All Methods of Sanitizing SQL in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, sql-injection

I've inherited a large-scale website written in CakePHP for my senior project. Unfortunately, it's highly vulnerable to SQL injections. I've never used CakePHP before so I'm trying to make sure I understand what all needs to be done. When using the save and find functions is all I have to do is use proper array notation to prevent SQL injections? For using the query method is all I have to do is use prepared statements? However, are there any other commands and methods I need to do as well? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Typical" usage of cake's model class is going to always protect you from SQL injection vulnerabilities by properly escaping data and parameters coming and going.

BUT!!:

The model [query() method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query) assumes *you* will escape your parameters manually using the value() function which can be accessed in the models, e.g.:

```
$db = $this->getDataSource();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar='" . $db->value($param, 'string') . "'";
$data_array = $this->Foo->query($sql);
```

FYI if you need to access the value() function in a controller, you have to do something like:

```
   $db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
   ...
```

And as you mentioned, you can also use [prepared statements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#prepared-statements), in which case the driver itself handles the escaping.

Be mindful that, while *standard* usage of the model methods (other than query()) will handle everything for you, there are funky things you could do -- like passing parameters through array keys or creating complex finds (e.g., full text MATCH ... AGAINST syntax) -- that will still require you to prevent SQL injection vulnerabilities via manual coding!

In general, try to avoid query() and/or prepared statements whenever the ORM and standard model methods will do the trick!

With any framework, trust but verify. I.e., use API doc to confirm advertised functionality. E.g.,:

http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/class-Mysql.html#_value

Comment: So find and save don't require a special array with rules? Also, thank you very much for all the help.

Comment: Find and save do not require any special rules. Also be aware that for custom finds you can avoid using the query() method by writing custom find types in your model. This has the benefit of being re-usable as well as leveraging Cake's in built query protection. See here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-custom-find